# javax.security.auth.login exceptions

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

The code is trying to authenticate against an LDAP server. When the user's password or account is expired it has to throw an error.

When I try to login with an expired password/account a `FailedLoginException` is thrown:

```
FailedLoginException! Password Incorrect/Password Required.
```

Where as the documentation says it should throw a `AccountExpiredException` or `CredentialExpiredException`.

How can I found whether a password or account is expired?

Below is my code (simplified).

```
            //Create login context
            LoginContext lc = null;
            try {
                lc = new LoginContext("applicationPolicyName", new UsernamePasswordHandler(username, password));
            } catch(LoginException le) {
                log.info("LoginContext cannot be created. "+ le.getMessage());
            } catch(SecurityException se) {
                log.info("LoginContext cannot be created. "+ se.getMessage());
            }               
            try {
                lc.login();
            } catch (AccountExpiredException e) {
                log.info("AccountExpiredException!. "+ e.getMessage());
            } catch (CredentialExpiredException e) {
                log.info("CredentialExpiredException!. "+ e.getMessage());
            } catch (FailedLoginException e) {
                log.info("FailedLoginException!. "+ e.getMessage());
            } catch(LoginException le) {
                log.info("Authentication failed. " + le.getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The directory server might return a password expiring or password expired response control in the bind response. LDAP clients should always check the LDAP response for response controls, and APIs that do not support the manipulation of controls should not be used for non-trivial code. See also "[LDAP: Account Status](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/status-of-user-accounts-in-a-directory-server-database/)".